# How to set Cmnd_Alias properly?

Tags: sudo

I have one script to allow for one user to run. The string calling it from the command line looks like

```
./script path/to/folder -a option='value'
```

When I try to add it to the other commands in Cmnd_Alias line, sudo blames sudoers file for incorrect syntax. How can I set such commands properly?

Comment: let me us know what things are you trying ?

Answer (score 1):

A command alias definition looks like this:

```
MyAlias = /absolute/path/to/script /absolute/path/to/folder -a option\='value', \
          /absolute/path/to/script /absolute/path/to/folder -a option\='othervalue'
```

Note the backslash before the `=` sign: you must escape characters that have a special meaning (`,:=\`). The backslash at the end of the first line means that the alias definition continues on the next line.

Note that `./script` and `path/to/folder` should be absolute paths. You can't know what the current directory will be when someone invokes `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing on escaping chars, but the first parameter of the script must be _relative_ path thanks to its author.

Answer (score 0):

Script can be specified without parameters.
http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7121802.html?sid=940bd372c7ebd5c9613fc318514c1d65#7121802